# replicas of quartz batchs in docker containers

Tags: docker, quartz-scheduler, batch-processing, redundancy

I have a quartz batch which is deployed in a docker container. The service is configured to run every minute. I need to deploy at least 2 replicas of each service (including batch) to ensure redundancy. I deploy my services with docker swarm and the container with the batch is deployed once on a VM1 and once again on a VM2.

The problem is that in this case, the 2 instances of the batch run at the same time and try to update the same data in the database.
I would like to configure the 2 instances of the batch so that one runs each even minute and the other each odd minute so that they don't run at the same time.

How can I have 2 different configurations for the 2 instances of the same service deployed with docker?

Comment: I think you need to reconsider how you think about the problem. You have 1 service you want to run continuously and you also want two replica services doing nothing just sitting there for 'redundancy' that are ready to start work (but only one of them!) if the main service fails. Things like Kubernetes are used to ensure you always have X services running - so you would tell K8s you want 1 running at all times and if the service fails K8s will restart it. So you don't need 'hot' standbys.  Other solutions and approaches are available depending on your exact requirement.

Comment: Hi, Docker Swarm can also restart a service if it fails. What I'd like is to have a second service in backup (but not running at the same time of the first one) in the case the VM hosting the first instance of the service crashes. We need high availability.

Comment: Providing high availability is achievable in many ways, depending on many factors. Having a 'standby' service does not necessarily provide high availability - if both the hot and standby services are in the same data centre and the centre goes down then you have no availability. You also cannot consider availability without considering the time to recover. Where you have a batch running every minute then your recovery time is greater than - for example - a 'live' website. So for high availability you may need to distribute your systems acrosses sites/zones, etc.